# Подключение botanio к telegram боту

Tags: java, telegram, бот

Привет! Создал Телеграм бота на java. Теперь прикручиваю yandex metrik'у. Выбрал Botan io. Т.к. документации особой нет, то пошли косяки: В общем, проблема на данный момент такова. Существует метод simpleAPIRequestShouldNotFail:

```
public static void simpleAPIRequestShouldNotFail(Message message) throws Exception {
    try (CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault()) {
        client.start();
        Botan botan = new Botan(client, new ObjectMapper());
        botan.track("42bc7b0a-d36a-40c8-bf13-aefe57ab5ee9", message.getChatId().toString(), message, message.getText()).get();
    };
}
```

На моменте HttpAsyncClients.createDefault() выдает исключение 
Exception in thread "rsreu Telegram Executor" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder.build(HttpAsyncClientBuilder.java:353)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClients.createDefault(HttpAsyncClients.java:49)
    at telegrambot.TelegramBot.simpleAPIRequestShouldNotFail(TelegramBot.java:50)
    at telegrambot.TelegramBot.onUpdateReceived(TelegramBot.java:73)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:271)

В чем может быть вообще проблема? Куда тыкаться? Что делать? Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, проблема решилась скачиванием HttpAsyncClient 4.1.3 c официального сайта. До этого я использовал HttpClient 4.5.3 . Из-за этого и возникла проблема.